# Does angular 1.X subscribes to changes into its controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I watched [the lesson](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-create-a-filter-with-angularjs) on egghead and I didn't quite understand rendering part. Basically there's a field in our controller `currentCategory` and `isCurrentCategory` checks whether the argument matches the inner field.

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-class="{'active':isCurrentCategory(category)}">
      <a ui-sref="eggly.categories.bookmarks({category: category.name})">
        {{category.name}}
      </a></li>
</ul>
```

The question is how does angular rerender everything (e.g., these bookmarks) when `currentCategory` changes (by `onClick` event)? I thought it'll work once (during the `init` stage while going through the whole `html` and then it shouldn't modify anything (you know, we haven't subscribe/listen to the changes to `currentCategory` and still rerendering every time it changes. How does it happen (how does controller class connect with a view in a reactive way)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS uses [two way binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_06), so changes to the controller will be reflected in the view, and changes in the view will be reflected in the controller.